# CloudFlare's cPanel plugin assigned new name servers for my domain - how do I make them use the old ones?

Tags: cpanel, nameserver, cloudflare

I deleted my domain in CloudFlare and recreated it using the CloudFlare plugin in cPanel, but CloudFlare gave me new nameservers that I should assign to my domain. The problem is that my registrar has to change nameservers manually and they don't work during the weekend.

My domain name is now pointing to the old CloudFlare nameservers which I can't update during the weekend, so my domain is unreachable. So how can I make CloudFlare assign the nameservers my domain is currently setup with?

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't have any control over what name servers CloudFlare assigns. However, I've found that when I delete domains from my CloudFlare account and then add them back later, they reassign the same name servers used previously (usually the same name servers are used for all the domains in your CloudFlare account). So perhaps if you undo the setup in cPanel via the CloudFlare plugin, and just add the domain back to your account on their website, the same name servers might be used again.

Comment: @dan Doesn't seem to work unfortunately. I can't see the nameservers either when I create it in cPanel. I'm just gonna have to wait for LeaseWeb I guess... thanks for the help tho :)

Comment: No problem. The issue might be that CloudFlare reads the current DNS info for the domain while adding it to their site, which is already with CloudFlare, so you might be forced to wait to update it with your DNS provider :-/ This is one of those tough lessons learned through experience, but maybe it will be helpful to someone else to know that the CloudFlare plugin might assign new name servers than what was assigned previously on their site.

Comment: @dan For future visitors I added an answer, just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conclusion: you can't control which nameservers CloudFlare assigns to your domain name.

> The issue might be that CloudFlare reads the current DNS info for the domain while adding it to their site, which is already with CloudFlare, so you might be forced to wait to update it with your DNS provider :-/ This is one of those tough lessons learned through experience, but maybe it will be helpful to someone else to know that the CloudFlare plugin might assign new name servers than what was assigned previously on their site. - Dan

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the webhost manager interface? It's like cPanel on steroids.

Or you could issue a 302 redirect to a different DNS resolver.

Use a free or cheap DNS until cloudflare is open. Do you have any ability to set the nameserver host name itself? That might be a decent temporary fix.

Comment: >> Do you have any ability to set the nameserver host name itself? - No, that's the whole problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't have to switch to our nameservers when signing up through a panel option (that integration works via a CNAME).

Comment: I think the issue was that the OP already had CloudFlare name servers specified with the domain registrar, then deleted that domain from his CloudFlare account when he used the CloudFlare cPanel plugin instead, which resulted in new name servers being assigned. He wasn't able to update the name servers with the domain registrar over the weekend however so was stuck. Can you suggest a workaround/solution in that situation? If you email your support team, can they reassign previous name servers in the case where a user is not able to update the name servers again with their registrar?

Comment: They would not be using our nameservers when they signup through the panel option. If they are using the panel option at a hosting partner,  then they would be using their host's or registrar's nameserver (the partner integrations work via a CNAME & do not require changing to our DNS). CloudFlare can't update nameservers at the registrar for the OP, nor do we we have any control over any propagation issues that their registrar has in making a change.

Also: We can only provision CNAMEs when activating through a partner. The domain would be more secure when signed up directly.

Comment: When I checked the OP's DNS record for their domain, it was using CloudFlare's name servers, not the host's or registrar's, so there must have been some miscommunication in the question. In any case they just had to wait a bit to be able to update any needed changes with their registrar. It sounds like there's fewer parties in the mix when you manage a domain through your website. Thanks for the clarifications.